# How to auto click OK of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, timer, joptionpane

I have a `JOptionPane`. If a user does not click it in 10 minutes, then the `JOptionPane` should auto click OK.

How can I do this?

Comment: [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) could be helpful.

Comment: Does JOptionPane have some native option to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a `JDialog` from a `JOptionPane` object. Then, create a timer to run for 10 minutes (600,000 milliseconds), and dispose the dialog once it has finished. Then, retrieve the chosen value from your `JOptionPane` object, making sure to account for an uninitialized value if the dialog was disposed by your timer.

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Hello world?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Hello world");
        Timer timer = new Timer(600000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }

        });
        timer.start();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
        Integer choice = (Integer) (pane.getValue() == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE ? JOptionPane.OK_OPTION : pane.getValue());
    }
}
```